# How to activate 2-Factor Authorization with authenticator for a Google account?

Tags: google-account, multi-factor-auth, google-authenticator

When I want to add 2FA with the Google authenticator, Google always want to add 2FA with Phone verification instead.

I Googled it and all articles are mentioning the same URL, which asks for a phone number instead of generating an authenticator key.

What do it need to do, to activate the authenticator verification instead of phone/SMS verification?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up Google Authenticator without giving a phone number?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43188/setting-up-google-authenticator-without-giving-a-phone-number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even to activate the Authenticator, first you need to complete [SMS/Voice setup](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839).

Then, follow the directions for your type of device explained on Google Help page for [2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?hl=en&rd=1).

Read this [Make Your Email Hacker Proof](https://blog.codinghorror.com/make-your-email-hacker-proof/) for more understanding.

Comment: Meh. I wanted the authenticator app, to avoid giving google my phone number. The app is such a nice idea for 2FA without giving out too many personal details ...

Comment: Could I add someone's phone number, set up TOTP 2FA, then remove the phone number?